# what is the proper way to call models in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Chefs have one Location and Location belongs to Chef.

In the Locations controller, how do I call chefs.  Below is what I have so far.

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @chef = Location.find_by_chef_id #This is what I am not getting.  Should it be,
    @chef = Location.find(params[:chef_id])??
    @locations = Location.all
  end
end
```

I am wanting to call it in my view with something like <%= chef.name %>

Could this be correct?

```
@location= Location.find(params[:id])
@chef = Chef.find(@location.chef_id)

@chef.each do |chef|
    <%= chef.name %>
end
```

This brings up this error "Couldn't find Location without an ID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call any model from your LocationsController:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @chefs = Chef.all
    @chef = Chef.find(params[:id])
    @locations = Location.all
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

If you want to call a chef's name in the view:

```
@location.chefs.each do |chef|
  <%= chef.name %>
end
```

It all depends what type of content you're trying to render, but it's best to call models directly in the controller unless certain associations are required.

```
@location.chefs.each do |chef|
  if !chef.name.blank?
    <%= chef.name %>
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok this makes sense, but why do I get this error?  "Couldn't find Chef without an ID"  Why is it looking for a chef without an id?

Comment: That would be because `params[:id]` is `nil`. What does your request look like?

Comment: Do all of your Locations have at least one Chef associated with them?

Comment: Not all of my Chefs have Locations.  Could that be an issue?

Comment: You could add and an `if / else` statement to check. I've updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: if else statement is not doing anything still getting ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LocationsController#index Couldn't find Chef without an ID

Comment: I would recommend defining the variables in your console, and then testing your loop / statements there for troubleshooting. Just swap out the erb tag with puts "chef.name".

Answer (score 1):

If each Location `belongs_to` a Chef, then:

```
@locations = Location.includes(:chef).all
```

Then you can iterate over these:

```
@locations.each do |location|
   location.chef
end
```

Or if you want all the chefs:

```
@chefs = @locations.collect(&:chef).uniq
```

There's probably a better way to fetch this, but it's not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: Q.. Being a new Rails guy asking - Why does eager loading you suggested ?

Comment: It avoids a so-called N+1 load where you'd have to load each chef individually when iterating over your locations. It's almost always a good idea if that data will be used.

Comment: Okay is `eager loading` is always advisable ?

Comment: Like I said, if you're going to use the data it's probably the best plan. It's a bad idea if you have no use for the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for `Location` by `id`, and then just get its chef.

```
def index
   @location = Location.find(params[:id])
end
```

then in view:

```
@location.chef.each do |chef|
   <%= chef.name %>
end
```

and if `chef` can be `nil` use `#try` method:

```
@location.chef.try(:each) do |chef|
   <%= chef.name %>
end
```

But the `Location` model shell include `belongs_to` declaration:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :chef
end
```

Comment: Stll get this dang error. Couldn't find Location without an ID

Comment: `chef.each` makes no sense if it's a `belongs_to` relationship, though. The `try` version is a good way to do it.

Comment: @Seal what the behavious should be when id is absent?